# SQL Server weird +'='+ thing

Tags: sql-server

I just ran across this in some code:

```
SELECT column1 +'='+ column2 . . . .
```

Does anyone know what `+'='+` does? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @AndrewMartin there are other cases where people have been (understandably!) confused: `while (i --> 0)` is the "goes to zero" operator. The human eye tokenizes differently than the machine does.

Answer (score 7):

It concatenates the string `=` together with the specified columns. It is called the "*concatenate an equals sign operator*" :) Strangely, MSDN does not document that operator.

Joking aside: Format your code properly:

```
SELECT column1 + '=' + column2
```

Comment: ( as a bit offtopic thing -- I would've also mention the `select @myparam=myColumn ,...` syntax  - which also includes '='...)

Answer (score 4):

It's concatenating those column values into a single string, with a `=` character in between.

So if the value of `column1` is "this" and the value of `column2` is "that" then the resulting selection will be the string: `"this=that"`

Answer (score 2):

It is string concatentation.

Put some spaces in there , and it won't look so weird to you. (And will not change functionality) .. this is kinda like

```
Select LastName + ', ' + FirstName as FullName from dbo.MyTable
```